# jwplayer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I've downloaded the files and followed the steps provided but the player simply isn't working.

```
    <code>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "/player.swf",
    file: "/video.mp4",
    height: 270,
    width: 480
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    </code>
```

All it shows is "Loading the Player." As you can see I've linked the JWplayer and jquery scripts. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I use web expressions... when I try to follow the jwplayer link "jwplayer(container)," i says that a link could not be found.

Comment: Can you post what errors your debugger shows? Also, where are the player.swf, video.mp4 jwplayer.js, and jquery.js files located? Are you able to access them in your address bar using http://example.com/player.swf, etc... ?

Comment: Try using relative address in the `src` attribute or try using ~/ for the home attributes.

Comment: jwplayer is not defined
http://irvinetireoutlet.com/landslide.html
Line 35      .......................................................... That's what I though the problem was...

Comment: remove / from the properties like jsimport,flashplayer etc,. Btw check using firebug plugin in firefox to see all the files are loading properly

Answer (score 6):

Try this code. With relative address, it works for me! I hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.9.2/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
            flashplayer: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.9.2/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.swf",
            file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4",
            height: 270,
            width: 480
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is the need of jquery file

Comment: i kept it, because it was in his example. don't know her dependancies.

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of the `/` in your code so that it reads as follows:

```
flashplayer: "player.swf"
```